# Dropdown Navigation in Html5 not working properlly

Tags: php, css, html, wordpress

I am creating a Wordpress theme and am trying to get the navigation working properly, but I am having issues with some of the CSS needed to create a dropdown menu.  The list hierarchy for the navigation is getting generated correctly, but remains as an unordered list instead of becoming a dropdown list. I have tried opening the site in several different browsers, but the result is the same. Here is the php/html5:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="site-navigation main-navigation"></nav>
    <h1 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'shape' ); ?></h1>
    <div class="assistive-text skip-link"><a href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e('Skip     to content', '_s' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'shape' ); ?></a></div>
    <?php wp_page_menu('title_li=&sort_column=menu_order&show_home=1') ?>
</nav>
```

Here is the CSS I am using:

```
.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5em;
}
.main-navigation:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
.main-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.main-navigation li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    position: relative;
}
.main-navigation a {
    color: #7c948a;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.main-navigation ul ul {
    background: #e9e0d1;
    border: 1px solid rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.1 );
    display: none;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
        top: 1.2em;
        left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.main-navigation ul ul a {
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    width: 200px;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li {
}
.main-navigation li:hover > a,
.main-navigation li.current_page_item a,
.main-navigation li.current-menu-item a,
.main-navigation ul ul a:hover {
    color: #33605a;
}
.main-navigation ul ul :hover > a {
}
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

/* Small menu */
.menu-toggle {
    color: #7c948a;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.main-small-navigation .menu {
    display: none;
}`
```

I am rather new to PHP and Html5, so it is possible that I am missing something simple. Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: Example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is broken. You are closing the `<nav>` twice. Remove the closing tag `</nav>` from line one.

```
<nav role="navigation" class="site-navigation main-navigation">
    <h1 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'shape' ); ?></h1>
    <div class="assistive-text skip-link"><a href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e('Skip     to content', '_s' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'shape' ); ?></a></div>
    <?php wp_page_menu('title_li=&sort_column=menu_order&show_home=1') ?>
</nav>
```

I'm assuming the PHP output will be something like [THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4tWBQ/2/)